# Apache Axis 1.4 generated classes compatible with JBoss 7?

Tags: web-services, jboss7.x, axis, soap-rpc-encoded

We're migrating an application from JBoss AS 5.1 to JBoss AS 7.4 (EAP 6.3). In there, we consume an RPC encoded web service.

We had used the Sun XML RPC lib to autogenerate Java source from the WSDL, which was awfully old even back then, and some SAAJ version related conflicts occurred which were just so resolvable in the JBoss environment. So we ruled out using the Sun RPC lib in the JBoss 7 environment.

It was suggested to us to use Axis 1.4 to generate classes from the WSDL. However, it is also ancient (2006), so I'm afraid we'd just end up with a similar conflict as with Sun RPC.

So I'm wondering whether anyone has sucessfully deployed classes autogenerated from Axis 1.4 in JBoss 7 (on Java 7) and whether they encountered library conflicts?

Comment: Have you tried and it blew up

Comment: In the meantime I have, and it didn't blow up. I'm holding back on the verdict until I finish testing, but so far it appears Axis 1.4 generated code is indeed compatible with JBoss 7.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I had to add these artifacts:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>axis</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
  <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

which didn't cause any conflicts in JBoss EAP 6.3. I was kinda expecting a SAAJ conflict, but it appears to serve as a client for the webservice, Axis doesn't need SAAJ (or it's content to use the SAAJ it finds in the platform)